# Excel/VBA combine tables

Tags: excel

In my mind this shouldn't be difficult so it's all the more frustrating that I can't figure it out.  This is in Excel 2016 and VBA.  What I'm trying to do is copy 2 different tables of data in 2 different tabs and combine them in a third tab using a simple button.  A helpful user on Reddit got me started but I'm stuck on debugging.  Runtime error 438 occurs at the start of LRowB, I've verified the names of the tabs are correct.  Code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LRowA As Long
Dim LRowB As Long

LRowA = Sheets("PASSFAIL FEMALE").Cells(Sheets("PASSFAIL FEMALE").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("PASSFAIL FEMALE").Range("A2:H" & LRowA).Copy
Sheets("Final Test Stat Sheet").Range("A2").Paste

LRowB = Sheets("PASSFAIL MALE").Cells(Sheets("PASSFAIL MALE").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("PASSFAIL MALE").Range("A2:H" & LRowB).Copy
Sheets("Final Test Stat Sheet").Range("A2" & LRowA + 1).Paste

Sheets("Final Test Stat Sheet").Range("H27").Value = Now

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `Copy` and `Paste` the operations should be on the same line (and you can omit the latter).

But if you only want values and use `pastespecial` that does need to be on a separate line.

As an aside, using `With` can tidy up code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LRowA As Long
Dim LRowB As Long

With Sheets("PASSFAIL FEMALE")
    LRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:H" & LRowA).Copy
    Sheets("Final Test Stat Sheet").Range("A2").pastespecial xlvalues
End With

With Sheets("PASSFAIL MALE")
    LRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:H" & LRowB).Copy
    Sheets("Final Test Stat Sheet").Range("A" & LRowA + 1).pastespecial xlvalues
    Sheets("Final Test Stat Sheet").Range("H27").Value = Now 'might overwrite?
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: So this works, but I need the values copied, not the formulas that are being used to calculate them.  How would I specify that to VBA?

Comment: Amended above .